# How to bind a variable with multiple types? LINQ

Tags: c#, wpf, linq

I have been trying to bind a variable to WPF. I am using LINQ to get the data. The criteria is a unique `int` type and returns a single row of data that has 30 columns, of which there are several different types that need to be returned.

I am getting this error [InvalidOperationException Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(EHInvalidOperation);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5.2);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true), but I can't figure out how to fix this?

This is what I have thus far,

```
internal class DatabaseQueries
   {
       public static IEnumerable<int> ModValues(DatabaseDataContext database, int staffNo)
            {
                return database.Staff_Mod_TBLs
                    .Where(staff => staff.Staff_No == staffNo).Cast<int>().ToList();

            }
   }
```

This is the code that set the variable,

```
int staffNumber = 192356;
            var modTblValue = DatabaseQueries.ModValues(sql, staffNumber);
```

And the XAML, (for some reason I can't post all the XAML, so this is an abbreviated snip of code.)

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <TextBlock FontWeight="Normal" Text="{Binding Path=modTblValue, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
```

Comment: Bind your `modTBlValue` as a property. binding only works with properties.

Comment: @AbinMathew, I am not sure I follow? Sorry, still learning all this.

Comment: `.Cast<int>()` - where did you see that? Go and learn `Select`. `Select`, `Where` are pretty basic things, you can't use LINQ without knowing at least the basic constructs.

Comment: @IvanStoev, I believe that is called `The process of learning something you don't already know`. If I knew everything there was to know about LINQ, I am sure I would not be in the pickle. I am sure you can relate to when you wrote your first `Hello world` line of code? So you suggest using select? I followelled the error message that said I was missing a cast, that is why that is in there. I have literally searched dozens of pages to get where I am right now.

Comment: @IvanStoev, how do I use select to get 30 columns of data?

Comment: The same way you select 2 columns.

Comment: @IvanStoev, you have to write out 30 columns in the linq query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a property like below,

```
private string _modTblValue;
public string modTblValue 
    {
        get { return _modTblValue ; }
        set { modTblValue = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
    }
```

Assign the value you get from DataBase to `modTblValue`

```
 modTblValue = DatabaseQueries.ModValues(sql, staffNumber);
```

Bind your property `modTblValue` with UI

```
<TextBlock FontWeight="Normal" Text="{Binding Path=modTblValue, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

If you need a collection of your property to bind to a `DataGrid` then create a `class` which contain your `Properties`, and make a property of list of your class to bind as `ItemSource` of your `DataGrid`

[Check this too.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.itemssource(v=vs.95).aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the help, that clears up a part of all this that I was not doing correctly. But I still get an error with the query.

Comment: Yes, the LINQ query seems to be the problem. As Ivan stated in the comments, I need to use select. But, I can't get past the combine error when making one with select.  InvalidOperationException Class error

Comment: Your return type is of `IEnumerable<int>` and consider reading [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg509017.aspx)

Comment: I have been over that page many times, but I can't get the syntax correct to put the query into its own class???

Comment: Hey, I still can't get this syntax correct. I am going to mark this answer as the best answer. Thanks for the help.

Comment: create a new question with the queries you ware trying.

Comment: See here , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38126976/create-a-class-that-will-hold-a-linq-query