# Create a class that will hold a LINQ query?

Tags: c#, linq

This question is a continuation of the this question, [How to bind a variable with multiple types? LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38125748/how-to-bind-a-variable-with-multiple-types-linq)

I am trying to select a row of data that has 30 columns in it, the criteria is a unique value from the column `Staff_No`. The row has several data types.

I can't get the the syntax correct and this is the code.

```
internal class DatabaseQueries
   {
       public static IEnumerable<int> ModValues(DatabaseDataContext database, int staffNo)
            {
                return database.Staff_Mod_TBLs
                    .Where(staff => staff.Staff_No == staffNo).Cast<int>().ToList();

            }
   }
```

The error is [InvalidOperationException Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(EHInvalidOperation);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5.2);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true).

And this code gives me this error,

```
 public static IEnumerable<decimal> ModValues(DatabaseDataContext database, int staffNo)
        {
            return database.Staff_Mod_TBLs
                .Where(staff => staff.Staff_No == staffNo).Select(staff => staff.Days_No_D).ToList();
        }
```

The error, `Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Error CS0266 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<decimal?>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<decimal>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)`

Comment: Why are you trying to case to an `int`?  If you just want a record from the database, why is the method returning a collection?  Are you just looking for `.Single(staff => staff.Staff_No == staffNo)`?

Comment: Are you wanting the whole row or just an `int` column?  Shouldn't your return type be `IEnumerable<Staff_Mod>` or something? If you just want _one_ row set the resutn type to the class and use `Single` or `SingleOrDefault`

Comment: I was trying to get the whole row which has several data types.

Comment: Then why are you casting the objects into ints?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I am trying to select a row
>   [and in a comment...]
>   I was trying to get the whole row which has several data types.

Then you don't need to `Cast()` or `ToList()`.  If you want a single record, just fetch that single matching record:

```
return database.Staff_Mod_TBLs
               .Single(staff => staff.Staff_No == staffNo);
```

or, if you want to return `null` instead of throwing an error when there's no match:

```
return database.Staff_Mod_TBLs
               .SingleOrDefault(staff => staff.Staff_No == staffNo)
```

Then of course you'd need to change the method's return type:

```
public static Staff_Mod_TBL ModValues(...)
```

(Assuming the type name based on the table name.  Substitute as needed if it's different.)

Basically, what you are looking for is an instance of the object which represents a record in that table.  Not a collection of column values.

Comment: I am trying to get 30 columns of data , or is that the wrong way of thinking? I want to have those 30 columns bound to a datagrid.

Comment: @KyloRen: Those 30 columns would be 30 properties on the object being returned, each named for one of the columns.

Comment: OK, so I need to literally write out every column into a property in a single query?

Comment: @KyloRen: What do you mean?  The data access framework (Entity Framework?  LINQ to SQL?  Something else?) would map the columns to the object for you.  (If it doesn't, get a better data access framework.)  All this method needs to do is return the instance of the object you're looking for.  Note in this answer the only column explicitly referenced is the one being used in a comparison.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can Cast `Staff_Mod_TBLs` to `int`, this is invalid

You're really mixing things here :

`.Cast<int>` converts each element to `int`.

If you want to return the whole object based on a filter:

```
public static Staff_Mod_TBLs ModValues(DatabaseDataContext database, int staffNo)
        {
            return database.Staff_Mod_TBLs
                .FirstOrDefault(staff => staff.Staff_No == staffNo);
        }
```

Comment: That is exactly what I have been trying to get to work, but it gives me a compile error.

Comment: `Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Error CS0266 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<decimal?>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<decimal>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)` I an guessing this is the problem? `public static IEnumerable<decimal> ModValues(DatabaseDataContext database, int staffNo)`

Comment: @KyloRen Can you post the query that is generating this error in your question ? or just change return type to `IEnumerable<decimal?>`

Comment: @KyloRen check the updated answer, just change the return type to `IEnumerable<decimal?>` and it should work

Comment: OK, that is working for me. Obviously this code does not work, `.Select(staff => staff.Days_No_D && staff.Day_Off).ToList();`, but how do I write the code to get the rest of the 29 columns data?

Comment: @KyloRen: If you want all the data in that record, don't filter it out with a `.Select()`.  Just take the record that comes back as-is.  Remove the `.Select()` entirely.

Comment: @David OK, I see. But the issue I keep getting is that you can't pass a `<var>` instead of the `<decimal?>` , there are different datatypes in several of the columns.

Comment: @KyloRen You can use `Tuple.Create()` or create your own class and then `.Select (staff => new MyClass() { a = staff.something, b = something})`; and change method return type to `IEnumerable<MyClass>`

Comment: @KyloRen: Refer to the answer I posted.  The data type being returned by the query is the type you would return from your method.

Comment: @KyloRen do you want to return the whole object, or just some properties of it ? Please be precise.

Comment: @user3185569 I want the whole 30 columns of data for that single row, if that is called the object, then yes.

Comment: @KyloRen: Then return the whole object.  Stop trying to turn an entire object into a single scalar value.

Comment: @David, Something like this? `public static Staff_Mod_TBL ModValues(DatabaseDataContext database, int staffNo, decimal staffDecimal)
        {
            return database.Staff_Mod_TBLs
                .Where(staff => staff.Staff_No == staffNo);
        }`  , But this gives me compile error.

Comment: @KyloRen: That's because you're trying to return a collection when the method's return value is a single instance.  Refer to the answer I posted to return a single instance.

Comment: @KyloRen then you should use `.FirstOrDefault` and not `.ToList`. Check the answer.

Comment: OK, I am now starting to see where I am going wrong. Let me test some of this. Thanks.